# Was the Rogue One title the first use of a seriffed font?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Perhaps I'm just misremembering, but I found the seriffed font (Times New Roman or similar) for the main *Rogue One* title card jarring.

Is this the first use of a seriffed font on-screen in a *Star Wars* movie?

(For the purpose of this question anything that appears on-screen during the main film, including titles, subtitles, on-screen setting labels, but not the ending credits, production company logos, etc.)

Comment: Gotta love the silent downvote.

Comment: I upvoted to balance, but an authoritative source citing that RO was serif and, for example, ANH was sans serif, would clearly improve the question

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida:   Well, I can promise that the title in Rogue is, and all the subtitles and location labels are not.   *A long, long time ago...*  and the opening crawl in all the movies clearly are not.   I believe that the movie poster logos for the movies did contain serifs, but I don't think the movie titles themselves did.   Until proven otherwise.

Comment: Rogue One was the first Star Wars movie without the crawl, so that's probably what prompted use of the poster title and its serif font.  The serif font use on posters goes back to Return of the Jedi.

Comment: I knew this was your question from the title alone.  Happy New Year!

Answer (score 6):

### Probably so

Most on-screen text in *Star Wars* is in Aurabesh, introduced in *Return of the Jedi*. The original tractor beam controls from *A New Hope* (a.k.a *Star Wars*) were in English, but I can’t spot any serifs in the text.

[image: enter preformatted text here]

The opening crawl and closing credits in every main *Star Wars* movie seems to be [News Gothic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_Gothic):
[image]

The fonts used for the rest of the opening frames are elaborated on [here.](http://www.theforce.net/fanfilms/postproduction/crawl/opening.asp)

**None of these fonts have serifs, and they constitute most of what’s seen onscreen in *Star Wars*.**

That said, serif fonts have certainly appeared in the promotional material for these films. According to [this article](http://www.zevendesign.com/star-wars-force-awakens-terrible-font-choice/), the font for *The Force Awakens* trailer is “bold weight ITC **Serif** Gothic.” [Apparently](https://www.typewolf.com/site-of-the-day/fonts/itc-serif-gothic) the serifs are subtle, but they’re there, as can be seen in this image:

[image]

Going back a bit further, this is also the same font that was used for some of the original *Star Wars* posters.

Comment: In space no one can hear you serif